# Caracteres raros en XML

Tags: php, xml

En php llamo a un servicio que me devuelve un XML. El problema que tengo es que dentro del XML puede haber caracteres extraños que me rompen el XML a la hora de leerlo. Para leer el XML estoy utilizando la libreria `SimpleXMLElement` y la línea que me rompe el XML es esta:

```
RACIÓN Y SEGUIMIENTO DE ESTRATEGIAS ENFOCADAS A LA GENERACIÓN DEL NEGOCIO&#xB
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para escapar esos caracteres?

Un saludo.

---

Así es como recibo el XML:

```
    $ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
    syslog(LOG_INFO,'url_offers_cornerstone '.$url_offers_cornerstone.$filter);
    $result = file_get_contents($url_offers_cornerstone.$filter, false, $ctx);

    // Escapamos caracteres especiales en el XML
    //$result = htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_XHTML,'UTF-8');
    $resultt = remove_utf8_bom($result);

    // Parseo y tratamiento del espacio de nombres
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($resultt);

    // guardo en el bucket el fichero devuelto por CSOD
    global $bucket;
    $filename = $bucket . 'CSOD_offers_' . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . '.xml';
    file_put_contents($filename, $result);

    $sxe->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'www.CornerStoneOnDemand.com/Services/ATS');
```

Comment: Según esta [página](http://www.codetable.net/hex/b), `&#xB` es una tabulación .Mira las respuestas de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28669407/4092887) o las de esta [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3426090/4092887). Si no has intentado, busca `php simplexml escape characters` en Google. Saludos.

Comment: Enrique, si solucionaste tu problema, recuerda publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.